# How do I check if my input on form is in 0000/0000 format?

Tags: java, string, format

I have a JFrame form with 2 text fields, both accept string as input, but one of those strings needs to be entered in format 0000/0000 (eg. 2008/0123), so it needs to have EXACTLY 9 characters. How should a code that checks whether the string is in 0000/0000 format be written? Thanks

Comment: You have your answer. Check in `String` class.

Comment: Have you check [this tutorial on formatted text fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis There are better ways to do it.

Comment: @assylias True. But maybe he should start with, arguably, the most used class in Java.

Comment: The `regex` library contains a `pattern` and `compiler` which allows you to easily achieve your goal of checking for pre-formatted text. These are used a lot for checking if a phone number is entered as a correct format.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
String text = txtField.getText();
boolean valid = text.matches("\\d{4}/\\d{4}");
```

You could combine this with a `DocumentListener` to give your field, for example, a red background if it doesn't validate.

```
{
    ...
    txtField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener(txtField));
    ...
}

class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {
    private JTextField txtField;
    public MyDocumentListener(JTextField field) {
        txtField = field;
    }

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        boolean valid = txtField.getText().matches("\\d{4}/\\d{4}");
        txtField.setBackground(valid ? Color.WHITE : Color.RED);
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { changedUpdate(e); }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { changedUpdate(e); }

}
```

---

**NOTE**: For i18n compatibility, you may wish to use `[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{4}` instead of using the `\d` class because `\d` can include non-Arabic numerals.